# Jenkins job sends notifications in 2 channels

Tags: jenkins, slack

Need to send notifications in 2 different slack channels ('all' and 'error') depending on failed or not Jenkins job.
Tried to add one more Post-Build Actions for slack but it's disabled:

[image]
Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

## Send the same notification to 2 channels

If you just need to send the same Slack notification to 2 channels, you can specify several channels in the Slack notification plugin (separated by comma):
[Example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGPKu.png)

## Send different notification to 2 channels

To send different notification to 2 channels, it's a bit more complicated. Some advices on internet advice to use the flexible publish, this way : [Example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn5B4.png)

But it's not working, but the Slack plugin have a problem and will use the same configuration for both messages (so you will have the same message to the 2 channels)

### Workaround

My workaround to this was to create my own incoming webhook (following this tutorial : https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks), and use it like this in my jenkins configuration : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmJ61.png)